# Currency based on payment Gateway in backend only woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Have have a custom plugin for my local payment method, we are using multicurrency on our website but our payment method only accepts the payment in 1 currency,

I am are using 2 currencies

USD and AED
Payment methods, Paypal, and Our Payment gateway.

The normal currency of our store is AED, but when someone reaches out to the website from outside of UAE, it shows $.

So we need a solution that, If someone is ordering on our site by choosing our payment gateway. This should be happen

```
if(Selected Payment Method is Custome Payment Gateway)
{

    if( Site current Currency = AED)
    {
    Send this price to the payment gateway in AED without doing anything.
    }
    else if (Site current currency = USD)
    {
    convert the price into AED and change the currency to AED then send the AED value to the payment gateway. like $*3.67 = AED
    }
}
```

All this should happen in the backend only when the custom payment method is selected, bypassing AED currency and value to the payment method, with no effect on the front end.

Comment: and what you use for multicurrency ? wpml ?

Comment: No, I am using "WooCommerce Price Based on Country (Basic)"